# Repair all mysql tables on localhost

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a whole bunch of mysql databases which seem to have corrupted tables which is a bit of a worry. Repairing them on one site fixed all the issues for that site, but is there a way of repairing all the tables in all databases on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If it is myiasm go into the dir and run

```
myisamchk -r *.MYI
```

Comment: yes it is cheers